# fileUploadField wicket 1.4.8 upload multiple files

Tags: file-upload, arrays, wicket

I have few queries with regard to fileUploadField in wicket 1.4.8. I want the user to have ability to upload one file at a time but should be able to upload many files before form submit.

1. I have included . User does select one file at a time and I display it as thumbnail on the page. I am simulating the behavior of  with a "Choose Image" button. He is then allowed to select another file. So, how do I get all these multiple files in wicket controller on form submit?

2.Most of the examples on fileUploadField available in google or on wicket site has below code snippet. Few things are not clarified here for me.

2.1. What is the getUploadFolder(). Is it the path for source file? or Is it the path for destination? I am allowing user to upload files from mobile device. So, if it is source path, how does it work in my case?

2.1.2. Also, I don't want to save the file either in my local disk or server side. I want the file data to be converted to byte[] and send across to downstream for further processing. Can I do that with fileUploadField or MultiFileUpload?

```
for (FileUpload upload : uploads)
                {
                    // Create a new file
                    File newFile = new File(getUploadFolder(), upload.getClientFileName());

                    // Check new file, delete if it already existed
                    checkFileExists(newFile);
                    try
                    {
                        // Save to new file
                        newFile.createNewFile();
                        upload.writeTo(newFile);

                        UploadPage.this.info("saved file: " + upload.getClientFileName());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to write file", e);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have looked around yourself, but have you seen the Wicket guide?
http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/chapter11.html#chapter11_7